# log and track proxy creation in JVM

Tags: java, classloader, byte-buddy, dynamic-class-creation

I have a class-loading problem in my app. We are using custom classloader and all is closed correctly but dynamic classes (`com.sun.proxy.* and org.springframework.core.$Proxy`) are generated pretty wildly and metaspace keeps growing to the point where JVM runs out of metaspace

I have tried a lot of things including heap and memory historgram analysis but I think I need some way to track proxy generation. I need to detect:

1. which objects are creating proxies
2. created proxy name

Is there any library / code snippet for that? I know I can technically use bytebuddy but dont want to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Java agent, you should log the class loading via the `-verbose:class` flag and process this output.